# Search Column headers Right to Left vba

Tags: excel, vba

I have a function to find a column header, but it searches from left to right. I need to find the right most column that matches, so I'd like to search right to left, but I can't figure out how. I tried using `xlprevious/xlnext` but they gave me the same answer.

Example:

```
Dim HeaderColFoundRng As Range
Set HeaderColFoundRng = Range("A1:H1").Find("FindStr", , xlValues, xlPart)
```

Comment: Did you mean `A1:H1` for example? `A1:A10` is one column so right-to-left doesn't make sense. Assuming you did, `Range("A1:H1").Find(What:="FindStr", LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)` worked for me.

Comment: fyi Late to the party, but you might be interested in an alternative approach to BigBen's valid solution using the new dynamic worksheet function `Filter()` available in MS 365 :-) @FreeSoftwareServers

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `xlPrevious` does seem to work for me:

```
Set HeaderColFoundRng = Range("A1:H1").Find(What:="FindStr", LookIn:=xlValues, _
    LookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
```

My guess as to why it didn't work for you is that you perhaps mixed up the argument positions. Using named arguments seems cleaner and easier to read here.

Answer (score 1):

**Alternative via worksheet function `Filter()`**

If you dispose of the dynamic Excel function `Filter` (vs. MS/Excel 365) you can use the following steps:

- a) construct a *formula* pattern returning column numbers (base formula e.g. `=FILTER(COLUMN(A1:H1),LEFT(A1:H1,8)="forecast")`),
- b) evaluate the formula to get 1-based *array elements* with all found column numbers. - The function returns the *most right* occurrence (`Right2Left`) of the searched caption (within each string starting with the passed caption characters) which will be located via `Ubound()`.

**Further hints:**

The search *caption* argument is *Case insensitive*. The Right to left direction can be changed via optional argument `Right2Left = False`.

```
Function HeaderCol(rng As Range, Caption As String, _
                   Optional Right2Left As Boolean = True) As Long
    'a) construct formula
    Dim addr As String
    addr = rng.Address(False, False, external:=True)
    Dim n As Long
    n = Len(Caption)
    Dim myFormula As String
    myFormula = "=Filter(column(" & addr & "),Left(" & addr & "," & n & ")=""" & Caption & """)"
    
    'b) get most right occurrence of evaluated formula (if Right2Left)
    Dim chk
    chk = Evaluate(myFormula)
    If IsError(chk) Then Exit Function
    HeaderCol = chk(IIf(Right2Left, UBound(chk), 1))
End Function
```

**Possible Example call**

Assuming a header row with changing column captions like `"Forecast2020"`, `"Forecast2021"`, `"Sales2020"`, `"Sales2021"` you might want to get the last occurrence of *Forecast* data, i.e. the column number of `"Forecast2021"`:

```
Sub testHeaderCol()
    Dim col As Long
    col = HeaderCol(Sheet1.Range("A1:H1"), "Forecast")
    If col Then
        Debug.Print "Found cell: " & Sheet1.Cells(1, col).Address(False, False, external:=True)
        'do other stuff, e.g. set range object
        '...
    Else
        Debug.Print "Nothing found!"
    End If
End Sub
```